# Which all folders will be included in serverless functions when packaging individually?

Tags: python-3.6, serverless

I am very new to the serverless framework and am very curious to know that when we execute "serverless package" and serverless.yml contains package individual as true then which folders will be added default to each functions.
Will it by default add all folders in every function or is their any specific condition for this ?

I have following directory structure:

```
|- service
|-- lambda_1
|---- main.py
|-- lambda_2
|---- main.py
|-- node_modules
|-- .git
|-- .idea
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the Serverless Framework will replicate the entire folder structure for each function that gets deployed. You can alter this by using some additional plugins that will optimise the packaging process per function. These plugins include:

- https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-webpack/ : Uses webpack to produce optimised bundles
- https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-optimize/ : Uses browserify instead of webpack
- https://serverless.com/plugins/serverless-parcel/ : Uses parcel